# when selecbox change call controllers method

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have select box which upon user selection should call controller method. This action should not be done using ajax, just "normal" traditional call to controller method

```
$("#MyTemplates").change(function () {
     var clicked = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
     if (clicked == "abc"){
        // call method controller/abc
     } else{
        // call method controller/x
     }
     ...    
});
```

Comment: give more details about what you want to achieve, post more code and explanation. this would help us solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following line to simply have the browser navigate to a new page without making an AJAX call.

```
window.location.href = '/controller/abc';
```

Assuming you're on example.com, the browser would go to example.com/controller/abc.